# Get all values of option fields and push it into an array

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have a photo upload system where the user have to set a category for each album to get the basics for a nice and clean search functionality. But if an user is changing now a value like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Choose a Category</option>
    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
</select>
```

to this:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Choose a Category</option>
    <option value="Holiday">Something Stupid</option>
</select>
```

is "something stupid" entered into the database.

That's why I have to do a server side check. But I don't know how to get all the correct values of the option fields to compare it with the posted value.

So my first considerations were the following:

PHP:

```
// Get all values of the option fields

// Push all the values into an array

if (in_array('foo', $array)) {
    // foo is in the array
}
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You should clarify your question, it has not only vague grammar, but also vague meaning.

Comment: Okay, (1) what is the sentence "The problem is that the bad boy user..." supposed to mean? and (2) What are trying to achieve? Unless you describe properly the problem, you can't get an answer.

Comment: I tried to explain it in a better way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I guessed what you tried to tell.

You should not have the  tags hardcoded in your `list.php` file, but instead have an array there. That way, you can use it both for generating the select field, but also for the verification. However, generally a database table with the categories would be preferable.

**path/list.php**

```
return array(
    '1' => 'Name of Ctg 1',
    '2' => 'Name of Ctg 2'
);
```

**Here you generate the select**

```
<select name="whatever">
<?php

$options = include('path/list.php');

foreach($options as $id => $name) {
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $name . '</option>';
}

?>
</select>
```

**And how to verify it then in the "target" page**

```
$options = include('path/list.php');
if(!array_key_exists( $valueFromUser, $options ) ) {
    // invalid option
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When the data is posted from the page containing the select tag, it will be in the $_REQUEST array, if you run this php in catcher php page:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST AS $key => $value) echo "$key = $value <br>";
```

you will see the results from your list.php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2180189/mightypork you nailed that one!  Well done.